# Spring batch : Exception on writer and rollback is done but no retry executed

Tags: spring, spring-batch, rollback, skip, writer

I encoutered a problem when an exception is occured in writer phase.

One item caused rollback due to an integrity problem in database, and no retry is executed, thus the processor is never replayed.

While an item caused rollback, it would be skipped. And others items are retry with interval-commit to one.

But, in my case, no retry is done for others items with interval-commit to one

Would you know for what reason no retry is executed ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Have you configured the exception to be retyable with `org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.FaultTolerantStepBuilder#retry`? Please share your code and your expectation to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you added the retry limit and the retry exception class needs to be listed in the retry-able list , check out below sample syntax for the same

```
 <job id="flowJob">
 <step id="retryStep">
 <tasklet>
 <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter"   processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="1"  retry-limit="3">
 <retryable-exception-classes>
 <include   class="org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException"/>
 </retryable-exception-classes>
 </chunk>
 </tasklet>
 </step>
 </job>
```